# jQuery: override fadein/fadeout effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to override jQuery's fadein and fadeout effects when page loads. How it is possible?

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by override effects?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override fadeIn and fadeOut ...
try this

```
jQuery.fn.fadeIn = function() {
  // yourcode here
}

jQuery.fn.fadeOut = function() {
  // yourcode here
}
```

Watch the movie a that [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-Ask-Ben-Overriding-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm)