# jquery fadeIn() on all browser but IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, overriding, unbind

I'm fading in some text when the page loads with jQuery. The opactity transition for text in IE 8 and less doesn't look very smooth and so therefore want to remove it.

Is there a way I can override the `fadeIn()` for only IE8 and less. Can I use an `unbind.('fadeIn')` with the following js file:

`<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/lte-ie8.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your IE specific JS file you can overwrite the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions like this:

```
$.fn.fadeOut = function () {
    return this.hide();
};
$.fn.fadeIn = function () {
    return this.show();
};
```

This will result in `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` calls being handled by the `.show()` and `.hide()` functions. This will also keep chain-ability intact.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ttGk5/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the useragent in javascript with the following:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/\bMSIE\b/)) {

}
```

Comment: I believe the question is regarding how to map `.fadeIn()` to `.show()` and `.fadeOut()` to `.hide()` as the OP has stated how to detect any IE browser less than version 9.

Comment: @Jasper Hmm alright, I guess I misunderstood OP's question. My apology.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redefine the functions instead of simply unbinding them. Unbind also removes an event that was bound to an element as well, so that will not have the intended effect here.

[jQuery: override fadein/fadeout effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182464/jquery-override-fadein-fadeout-effects)

You probably want to redefine fadeIn() and fadeOut() to alias show() and hide().